# How to give the uri in windows for Spring Cloud Config with Local Git repo?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I am trying to set up Spring Cloud Config Server. How to give the spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri in application.properties for Windows?

The uri is this one
D:\MicroservicesProject\git-localconfig-repo\test-service.properties

I tried this

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=D:\\MicroservicesProject\\git-localconfig-repo\\limits-service.properties
```

But I am getting this error

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: D:\MicroservicesProject\git-localconfig-repo\limits-service.properties: not a bundle
```

Comment: what are "all the ways" and what error do you get? Also, it should be a directory, not a file as listed.

Comment: @spencergibb edited question

Answer (score 3):

Try updating config line as follows:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///C:/Users/win10/Desktop/git-localconfig-repo/
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by making the path to the directory without specifying the name of the file.

```
D:\\MicroservicesProject\\git-localconfig-repo
```

Comment: Which is what I said in my comment above

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=D:/MicroservicesProject/git-localconfig-repo
```